# CodeIgniter disallow URL if not in route

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

This is my folder structure.

```
|--Application
|-----Controllers
|--------Dashboard.php
|--------Projects.php
|-----Models
|--------dashboardModel.php
|--------projectsModel.php
|-----Views
|--------dashboard (folder)
|-----------index.php
|-----------projects (folder)
|--------------add.php
|--------------index.php
```

Now, in my route file I have the following:

```
$route['default_controller']  = "dashboard";

$route['dashboard/projects']        = "projects";
$route['dashboard/projects/add']    = "projects/add";
```

Now the problem: if I type in the url `http://myproject/dashboard/projects` it works **AND** if I type `http://myproject/projects` it also works..how do I deny the second url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codeigniter URL mapping / routing works on the following process:

- Does an exact match for the URI exist in the routes array?
- Does a regex exist in the route array which matches the request?
- Try route to a controller matching the request using map: "controller[/method[/params]]"

So there is no setting to switch to stop it from routing to the last one...

you must extend the Router with a custom one like so:

in `application/core/` create a file called `MY_Router.php` this will house your custom router, and it will look something like this:

```
class My_Router extends CI_Router {
    function _parse_routes()
    {
        // Turn the segment array into a URI string
        $uri = implode('/', $this->uri->segments);

        // Is there a literal match?  If so we're done
        if (isset($this->routes[$uri]))
        {
            return $this->_set_request(explode('/', $this->routes[$uri]));
        }

        // Loop through the route array looking for wild-cards
        foreach ($this->routes as $key => $val)
        {
            // Convert wild-cards to RegEx
            $key = str_replace(':any', '.+', str_replace(':num', '[0-9]+', $key));

            // Does the RegEx match?
            if (preg_match('#^'.$key.'$#', $uri))
            {
                // Do we have a back-reference?
                if (strpos($val, '$') !== FALSE AND strpos($key, '(') !== FALSE)
                {
                    $val = preg_replace('#^'.$key.'$#', $val, $uri);
                }

                return $this->_set_request(explode('/', $val));
            }
        }

        // INSTEAD show 404..
        if (count($this->uri->segments) !== 0) {
            show_404();
        }
        else {
            // If we got this far it means we didn't encounter a
            // matching route so we'll set the site default route
            $this->_set_request($this->uri->segments);
        }
    }
}
```

the name of your class depends on what the `subclass_prefix` config variable is set to (by default its MY_ but you may have changed it..

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you. I saw that solution at http://codeigniter-blog.de/118/disable-automatic-uri-routing/, and I've tried and it did not worked totally. I had to add `$route['dashboard'] = "dashboard";` otherwise "projects" would work only as "dashboard/projects" BUT "dashboard" only page would not work.

Comment: if you want to change the behaviour of the core this is the way to go, which method you override, and how you do it to suit your requirements is up to you to figure out to be honest. I'm just giving an example.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been a year, but wanted to post for anyone else looking for an easier option.

You can always put something along these lines at the bottom of  config/routes.php. It'll catch any routes that haven't been picked up by a filter, and send them to where you specify. /auth/invalid generates a standard error message and returns it.

This allows me to whitelist URLs, so users cant access controllers in a way i might not plan for.

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = '/auth/invalid';
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = '/auth/invalid';
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = '/auth/invalid';
$route['(:any)'] = '/auth/invalid';
```